# How to log X-Forwarded-For in weblogic's access log?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, middleware, weblogic11g

Is it possible to log the `X-Forwarded-For` header in weblogic's `access.log` log file?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible.

Open your Weblogic administration console, go to Environment->Servers->[your server]->Logging->HTTP->Advanced

There, change Format to "Extended", and in Extended Logging Format Fields add cs(X-Forwarded-For)

This way you can put any http header into your access.log, see http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html for description of Extended log file format

Comment: thanks a lot. I have a similar requirement, but in our case the transport header has been named "Source-IP"... should I simply add cs(Source-IP), or is there any other settings to do on the webserver mbean? I see that there is a setClientIpHeader method defined on the webservermbean. If this is needed, how to make this configuration change permanent?

Comment: Yes, if your server is receiving a http header named Source-IP in the request, then adding cs(Source-IP) to logging format will place this header's value into access.log.